# Drain pipe issue

Tags: concrete, drain

I recently had a concrete  patio poured and I'm looking for some help on how to deal with where the water drains. I think  I need some type of metered catch basin. Right now " as is" my water flows back into the drain pipe.  [image]

Comment: What is the wall and what is behind the wall? Do you know the function of the drainpipe?   Was it the same before placing the concrete floor?

Comment: It looks like you need to trench to the left to provide the water under the structure a place to drain.